# Using chartJs in a Vue Component and a Webpack cli setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I am trying to build a chart using chartJs within a vue component,I am having a difficulty rendering it on my page. could someone please tell me where is my mistake?

```html
// this is my HTML canvas tag
<canvas  id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

the following is my Js code

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js';

  export default {
    methods: {
      CreateChart(chartId,chartData){
        const ctx =               document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
            labels: ['JavaScript','NodeJs','VueJs','DataBase'],
            datasets: [{
              label: '# of votes',
              data: [12,15,23,7],
              backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              ],
              borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
            }]
          },
          options: {
            scale: {
              yAxes: [{
                ticks: {beginAtZero: true}
              }]
            }
          }
        });
      }
    },
    mounted(){
      const data = {myChart}
      this.CreateChart('chart',data);
    }
  }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `myChart` variable in mounted hook?

Comment: {myChart} is the chart instance that I created using the `var myChart = new Chart(ctx,{...}` block!

Comment: I know perhaps its a very strange answer :D, but i'd appreciate if you can correct the mistake. thanks)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `scale` option you should use `scales`.

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    methods: {
      createChart(chartId,chartData){
        var myChart = new Chart(this.$refs.chart.getContext("2d"), {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
            labels: ['JavaScript','NodeJs','VueJs','DataBase'],
            datasets: [{
              label: '# of votes',
              data: chartData,
              backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              ],
              borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
            }]
          },
          options: {
            scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                ticks: {beginAtZero: true}
              }]
            }
          }
        });
      }
    },
    mounted(){
      let data = [12,15,23,7]
      this.createChart('chart',data);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <canvas id="chart" ref="chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much, that really helped, though if possible can you tell me how to target a specific bar in the graph, I want to be able to add, delete and change the value of the bar, but thanks anyway,  cheers)

Comment: @SwilamMuhammad you can save your config to variable and call `update` method of chart (see docs http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#updateconfig) when something changed